# Odoo no UserError message without any error

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9, raiserror

My code:

```
from openerp.tools.translate import _
from openerp.exceptions import UserError
```

and function:

```
@api.multi
def button_in_progress(self):
    for rec in self:
        rec.state = 'in_progress'
    test = self.test_ids.ids
    test1 = len(test)
    if test1 == 0:
        raise UserError(_('Test test'))
    return True
```

I logged. When I get test1 is 0, my error message doesn't appear. Also I don't get any of errors. What can be wrong?

Comment: Edit your question and correct the indentation ?

Comment: Log the value of `self.test_ids.ids` to be sure.

Comment: Everything is Ok now, thank you! The problem was because of my indentation.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

No need to find len and then check just try this

```
@api.multi
def button_in_progress(self):
    for rec in self:
        rec.state = 'in_progress'
    if not self.test_ids.ids:
        raise UserError(_('Test test'))
    return True
```